# Upload of some file fails using HttpClient

Tags: android, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x, bytearrayoutputstream, asynchttpclient

I am trying to upload images as well as videos to my external server from the app. I Googled and found out HttpClient procedure is a good one, so I downloaded the library and execute the following code which normally works well for every file however for some videos, it does not upload the video.

```
 public void executeMultipartPost(String uri) throws Exception {
    try {
        File file = new File(uri);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = readBytes(imageUri);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "http://example.com/ccs-business/upload.php");
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, file.getName());
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("uploaded_video", bab);
        reqEntity.addPart("number", new StringBody("123456"));
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
       Log.v("ONMESSAGE", "Response: " + s);
       dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception here
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

    }


    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

My requirement is to upload up to 20mb file.

Comment: send it in multiparts

Comment: I tried that too if you look at my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280006/resolving-java-lang-outofmemory-error-causing-half-of-the-file-to-be-uploaded-to

Comment: hmm , may be some issue with ur background part, i hvae myself develop app for 25 mb upload atlest

Comment: Can you provide a working code which can upload upto 20 mb of file and with that I can send some data too with the post

Comment: ok will post on ur above question

Comment: Hi @DIVA.....are you going to post the code here or on that above question?

Comment: above question , will provide source code but need to undo some of my officla code , will post in few hours

Comment: @DIVA..you have not posted the code you promised...Could you do it today?

Comment: ohh , m sorry i forgot i will post code in lunch time most probably

Comment: Hi @DIVA..I am waiting for the code...

Comment: willing to answer but busy with release of app , plz give me some time i will surly post and help

Answer (score 0):

I Have tired Uploading files with below code attached and worked fine :

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Utility method that creates the intent that starts the background
     * file upload service.
     *
     * @param task object containing the upload request
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if one or more arguments passed are invalid
     * @throws MalformedURLException if the server URL is not valid
     */
    public static void startUpload(final UploadRequest task)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, MalformedURLException {

        if (task == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't pass an empty task!");

        } else {
            task.validate();

            final Intent intent = new Intent(UploadService.class.getName());

            intent.setAction(ACTION_UPLOAD);
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_NOTIFICATION_CONFIG, task.getNotificationConfig());
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_ID, task.getUploadId());
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_URL, task.getServerUrl());
            intent.putExtra(PARAM_METHOD, task.getMethod());
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_FILES, task.getFilesToUpload());
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_REQUEST_HEADERS, task.getHeaders());
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_REQUEST_PARAMETERS, task.getParameters());

            task.getContext().startService(intent);
        }
    }

    public UploadService() {
        super(SERVICE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (ACTION_UPLOAD.equals(action)) {
                notificationConfig = intent.getParcelableExtra(PARAM_NOTIFICATION_CONFIG);
                final String uploadId = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_ID);
                final String url = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_URL);
                final String method = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_METHOD);
                final ArrayList<FileToUpload> files = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_FILES);
                final ArrayList<NameValue> headers = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_REQUEST_HEADERS);
                final ArrayList<NameValue> parameters = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(PARAM_REQUEST_PARAMETERS);

                lastPublishedProgress = 0;
                wakeLock.acquire();
                try {
                    createNotification();
                    handleFileUpload(uploadId, url, method, files, headers, parameters);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    broadcastError(uploadId, exception);
                } finally {
                    wakeLock.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleFileUpload(final String uploadId,
                                  final String url,
                                  final String method,
                                  final ArrayList<FileToUpload> filesToUpload,
                                  final ArrayList<NameValue> requestHeaders,
                                  final ArrayList<NameValue> requestParameters)
            throws IOException {

        final String boundary = getBoundary();
        final byte[] boundaryBytes = getBoundaryBytes(boundary);

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        OutputStream requestStream = null;

        try {
            conn = getMultipartHttpURLConnection(url, method, boundary);

            setRequestHeaders(conn, requestHeaders);

            requestStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            setRequestParameters(requestStream, requestParameters, boundaryBytes);

            uploadFiles(uploadId, requestStream, filesToUpload, boundaryBytes);

            final byte[] trailer = getTrailerBytes(boundary);
            requestStream.write(trailer, 0, trailer.length);
            final int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            final String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            broadcastCompleted(uploadId, serverResponseCode, serverResponseMessage);

        } finally {
            closeOutputStream(requestStream);
            closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }

    private String getBoundary() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("---------------------------")
               .append(System.currentTimeMillis());

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private byte[] getBoundaryBytes(final String boundary)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(NEW_LINE)
               .append(TWO_HYPHENS)
               .append(boundary)
               .append(NEW_LINE);

        return builder.toString().getBytes("US-ASCII");
    }

    private byte[] getTrailerBytes(final String boundary)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(NEW_LINE)
               .append(TWO_HYPHENS)
               .append(boundary)
               .append(TWO_HYPHENS)
               .append(NEW_LINE);

        return builder.toString().getBytes("US-ASCII");
    }

    private HttpURLConnection getMultipartHttpURLConnection(final String url,
                                                            final String method,
                                                            final String boundary)
            throws IOException {
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        return conn;
    }

    private void setRequestHeaders(final HttpURLConnection conn,
                                   final ArrayList<NameValue> requestHeaders) {
        if (!requestHeaders.isEmpty()) {
            for (final NameValue param : requestHeaders) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(param.getName(), param.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    private void setRequestParameters(final OutputStream requestStream,
                                      final ArrayList<NameValue> requestParameters,
                                      final byte[] boundaryBytes)
            throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (!requestParameters.isEmpty()) {

            for (final NameValue parameter : requestParameters) {
                requestStream.write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.length);
                byte[] formItemBytes = parameter.getBytes();
                requestStream.write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.length);
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadFiles(final String uploadId,
                             final OutputStream requestStream,
                             final ArrayList<FileToUpload> filesToUpload,
                             final byte[] boundaryBytes)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
                   IOException,
                   FileNotFoundException {

        final long totalBytes = getTotalBytes(filesToUpload);
        long uploadedBytes = 0;

        for (FileToUpload file : filesToUpload) {
            requestStream.write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.length);
            byte[] headerBytes = file.getMultipartHeader();
            requestStream.write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.length);

            final InputStream stream = file.getStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            long bytesRead;

            try {
                while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                    requestStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    uploadedBytes += bytesRead;
                    broadcastProgress(uploadId, uploadedBytes, totalBytes);
                }
            } finally {
                closeInputStream(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    private long getTotalBytes(final ArrayList<FileToUpload> filesToUpload) {
        long total = 0;

        for (FileToUpload file : filesToUpload) {
            total += file.length();
        }

        return total;
    }

    private void closeInputStream(final InputStream stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception exc) { }
        }
    }

    private void closeOutputStream(final OutputStream stream) {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception exc) { }
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection(final HttpURLConnection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception exc) { }
        }
    }

    private void broadcastProgress(final String uploadId, final long uploadedBytes, final long totalBytes) {

        final int progress = (int) (uploadedBytes * 100 / totalBytes);
        if (progress <= lastPublishedProgress) return;
        lastPublishedProgress = progress;

        updateNotificationProgress(progress);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(UPLOAD_ID, uploadId);
        intent.putExtra(STATUS, STATUS_IN_PROGRESS);
        intent.putExtra(PROGRESS, progress);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastCompleted(final String uploadId, final int responseCode, final String responseMessage) {

        final String filteredMessage;
        if (responseMessage == null) {
            filteredMessage = "";
        } else {
            filteredMessage = responseMessage;
        }

        if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299)
            updateNotificationCompleted();
        else
            updateNotificationError();

        final Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(UPLOAD_ID, uploadId);
        intent.putExtra(STATUS, STATUS_COMPLETED);
        intent.putExtra(SERVER_RESPONSE_CODE, responseCode);
        intent.putExtra(SERVER_RESPONSE_MESSAGE, filteredMessage);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastError(final String uploadId, final Exception exception) {

        updateNotificationError();

        final Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(UPLOAD_ID, uploadId);
        intent.putExtra(STATUS, STATUS_ERROR);
        intent.putExtra(ERROR_EXCEPTION, exception);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void createNotification() {
        notification.setContentTitle(notificationConfig.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notificationConfig.getMessage())
                    .setSmallIcon(notificationConfig.getIconResourceID())
                    .setProgress(100, 0, true)
                    .setOngoing(true);

        startForeground(UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
    }

    private void updateNotificationProgress(final int progress) {
        notification.setContentTitle(notificationConfig.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notificationConfig.getMessage())
                    .setSmallIcon(notificationConfig.getIconResourceID())
                    .setProgress(100, progress, false)
                    .setOngoing(true);

        startForeground(UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
    }

    private void updateNotificationCompleted() {
        stopForeground(notificationConfig.isAutoClearOnSuccess());

        if (!notificationConfig.isAutoClearOnSuccess()) {
            notification.setContentTitle(notificationConfig.getTitle())
                        .setContentText(notificationConfig.getCompleted())
                        .setSmallIcon(notificationConfig.getIconResourceID())
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                        .setOngoing(false);

            notificationManager.notify(UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID_DONE, notification.build());
        }
    }

    private void updateNotificationError() {
        stopForeground(false);

        notification.setContentTitle(notificationConfig.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(notificationConfig.getError())
                    .setSmallIcon(notificationConfig.getIconResourceID())
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                    .setOngoing(false);

        notificationManager.notify(UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID_DONE, notification.build());
    }
}
```

For compelete Source code refer [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8c4l59vpa71ubc4/android-upload-service-master.zip)